# Z3: How to select 4 bytes from array of 8-bits?

Tags: python, z3

With Python Z3, I have an array of bytes, and can use Select to read 1 byte like below.

```
MI = BitVecSort(32)
MV = BitVecSort(8)
Mem = Array('Mem', MI, MV)

pmt = BitVec('pmt', 32)
pmt2 = BitVec('pmt2', 8)

g = True
g = And(g, pmt2 == Select(Mem, pmt))
```

So far, this is OK. However, now I want to read 4 bytes out of Mem array, like below.

```
t3 = BitVec('t3', 32)
g = And(g, t3 == Select(Mem, pmt))
```

This turns out to be wrong, because t3 is 32-bit, not 8-bits, while Mem is the array of 8-bits.

The question is: How can I use Select to read out 4 bytes, but not 1 byte in the above example?

I suppose that I can create a new function to read out 4 bytes, lets say Select4(), but I am not sure how to create a function in Z3 python.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define `Select4` as

```
def Select4(M, I):
  return Concat(Select(M, I + 3), Select(M, I + 2), Select(M, I+1), Select(M, I))
```

The operation `Concat` is essentially appending the four Bit-vectors. Z3 also support the operation `Extract`. These two operations can be used to encode the casting operations available in programming languages such as C.

Here is the complete example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/OB2p)):

```
MI = BitVecSort(32)
MV = BitVecSort(8)
Mem = Array('Mem', MI, MV)

pmt = BitVec('pmt', 32)
pmt2 = BitVec('pmt2', 8)

def Select4(M, I):
  return Concat(Select(M, I + 3), Select(M, I + 2), Select(M, I+1), Select(M, I))

g = True
g = And(g, pmt2 == Select(Mem, pmt))
t3 = BitVec('t3', 32)
g = And(g, t3 == Select4(Mem, pmt))

solve(g, pmt2 > 10)
```

Comment: Leo, thanks so much. However, i think you forget to mention that you assume little-edian in the above code?